# Segmentation Fault on Initializing Large Arrays Using malloc() in C

Tags: c, memory-management

I am writing a simple code to add two very large matrices in C. Here is the code that I am using for memory allocation:

```
float *h_A, *h_B, *h_C;
size_t size=m*n*sizeof(float);

h_A = (float*) malloc(size);
h_B = (float*) malloc(size);
h_C = (float*) malloc(size);
```

However, on having m,n values >1000, it throws a segmentation fault. I have tried most of the other answers given on SO regarding this, but the error does not seem to go away. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Edit: It throws this error on m,n>100000, not 1000.

Comment: In what range are the values `m` and `n`? And when is the segfault thrown? During the call to `malloc` or later?

Comment: They are row size and column size, typically equal to each other.

Comment: N o, what is their value ? 10, 100, 1000, 10000, ...?

Comment: If you're getting a segfault, simply attempting to allocate memory, even a large amount, shouldn't cause that.  There's probably something else causing it.  Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I start them with 10, and they can go upto a million. I would like the code to run for m,n upto 10M.

Comment: Please answer my second question. It's essential, so we can answer.

Comment: @AdityaGrover A square matrix with a side length of 10M seems completely unreasonable, surely you understand that? You're talking about around 363 TB per matrix, at that point.

Comment: BTW if n = 10M you would allocate 10M * 10M = 100'000'000 Mb. In that case `malloc` will probbaly return `NULL` as your computer will not have enough memory.

Comment: Is there any workaround? I mean, I want them to go as high as possible. I am doing a comparison of running times b/w C and CUDA. I want to see how the difference changes with higher values.

Comment: Please check if `malloc` returns `NULL`. If yes, then `malloc` is unable to allocate the quantity of memory you are asking for.

Comment: _I am doing a comparison of running times b/w C and CUDA_: you don't need allocate that much memory for comparing execution times.

Comment: You should never cast the return of `malloc`

Comment: @MichaelWalz TIt does.

Comment: What does `malloc` return`? Why don't you check the result? Provide a [mcve]!

Comment: @Olaf malloc throws a null. I just checked.

Comment: 1) C does not support exceptions, so there is nothing **thrown**. 2) `malloc` returns a pointer. This can be a _null pointer_. What is "null"? So where is your segfault? I don't see any code which can generate one.

Comment: @AdityaGrover you mean _`malloc` **returns** `NULL`_ I suppose. Functions don't _throw_ anything in C. (In C++ the may throw an exception though),

Comment: @MichaelWalz: As we are nit-picking (both of us:-): `NULL` is a macro. macros cannot be returned by functions.

Comment: Guys I am getting overwhelmed with all the information I am being provided. Thanks, but I am not a C programmer, and mostly work in Java. So, excuse my naive mistakes.

Comment: You will have the same problems in Java. Did you even calculate how much memory `3 * 10000 * 10000` `float`s require?? And if you write code in C, get a good book and learn the basics first. C is not a language to learn by trial&error!

Comment: @Olaf Yeah, I guess that's a pretty big number. Never did such things in Java.

Comment: in java if you exceed maximum heap memory allowed it will throw `OutOfMemoryError` , how would you solve that ? you know how then that's mostly the answer to your problem, just needs conversion to C

Comment: Guys, I guess the problem is with malloc. So, I'll keep the value of m and n under 10000,

Comment: by the way on my system when I exceed RAM my OS begins to swap but believe me you don't want that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `size_t` is 32 bits, then when `m` and `n` are `>= 32768`

```
size_t size = m * n * sizeof(float);
```

will overflow yet produce a valid 32-bit number. This is then passed to `malloc` successfully, yet when you attempt to use the memory you imagine you have, but don't, it segfaults.

In the particular example where `n = m = 32768`, the product is `4294967296` so `0` is passed to `malloc` and indexing *any* of the supposed memory is illegal.

Comment: I guess that's exactly what's happening. Thanks @Weather Vane.

Comment: @AdityaGrover you commented you use 64-bit Ubuntu, does the compiler also generate 64-bit code? I use 64-bit Windows but my version of MSVC is 32-bit. I suggest printing the value of `size` to confirm there is no overflow in the multiplications.

Comment: for m,n=10, it prints a value of 400. So, I guess float's size is 32b in the generated code.

Comment: I mean, for the larger values which fail.

Comment: For m,n=100000, the value of size is 1345294336.

Comment: That is because `100000 * 100000 * 4 == 4000000000000` and `4000000000000 % 4294967296 == 1345294336` so QED you have an overflow.

Comment: P.S. I presume you did print `size` with `printf("%zu\n", size);`

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so `m == n == 100000` would give a matrix size of 100000 * 100000 * 4, or around 37 GB. That's approaching "large", even on modern server and desktop class machines.

Are you sure it's the `malloc()` that's segfaulting, and not some later code where you dereference a `NULL` pointer, or something? Could be that the allocation simply fails, returning `NULL`, but you don't check.

The code as shown really shouldn't segfault. The only typical case where `malloc()` segfaults is when earlier code has overrun an allocation, trashing the heap's internal data. Use Valgrind to help find those, if available.

Comment: I typed 1000 by mistake. It runs fine with m,n=10000. But when m,n=100000, it throws the error. Sorry for the naive mistake.

Comment: @AdityaGrover: Even **iff** `malloc` returns a valid pointer (read about optimistic allocation): does your machine have ca. 100GiB virtual memory available??

Comment: @Olaf I doubt that since I have a 128G SSD and 4G RAM. lol.

Comment: @AdityaGrover So why do you write such code? Do you use a 64 bit OS at least? Otherwise you have other problems, too.

Comment: Yeah, I use 64b Ubuntu. I'll be more careful in future.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this:

```
printf("m = %d, n = %d, size = %d\n", m, n, size);
h_A = malloc(size);
if (h_A == NULL)
{
  printf("Can't allocate memory for h_A\n");
  exit(1);
}

h_B = malloc(size);
if (h_B == NULL)
{
  printf("Can't allocate memory for h_B\n");
  exit(1);
}

h_C = malloc(size);
if (h_C == NULL)
{
  printf("Can't allocate memory for h_C\n");
  exit(1);
}

printf("All mallocs are OK\n");
```

This way you will get a correct diagnostic.

Comment: I don't understand. For m,n=100000, it sometimes prints "Can't allocate...". At other times, it just throws a segmentation fault error.

Comment: Don't cast `void *`. And that is possibly not the problem. OP already stated he knows it returns a null pointer.

Comment: After all the admonitions to never cast the result of an allocation why do you do it here?

Comment: @KevinDTimm I have removed all the casts, but the result remains the same.

Comment: @AdityaGrover - my question is for this answer

Comment: @AdityaGrover I edited this answer and added a `printf` at the end. Please do the same in your program and report what __exactly__ is printed on the screen when the segfault happens.

Comment: Alright, @MichaelWalz. I modified the code, as specified by you, and here is the output: All mallocs are OK
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @MichaelWalz Please note that this is for m=n=100000.

Comment: @AdityaGrover can you post the code that access's those variables ? you said you're summing matrices, is it a simple nested for-loop ?

Comment: @AdityaGrover OK, in that case Weather Vane's answer is probably what you are looking for.